# SQL fetch the first of assigned list

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Is it possible to fetch a database row based on the index of a list given?

I have a table lets call it 'storage'. The storage can have all sorts of string value in it. The list below present a possible list of value in storage. I don't know if any are present in the table. But I want to select the first value found depending on the order of the list given

List:

1. foo
2. bar
3. foobar
4. barfoo
5. oof

1.Foo and 2.bar don't exist but 3.foobar is. 3.foobar is the one I want to fetch.

Hopefully I am clear enough in my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Hopefully I am clear enough in my question." Well ... no ;)

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to be more accurate regarding the vocabulary: database ≠ table ≠ lists ≠ rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select col
from your_table
where col in('foo','bar','foobar')
order by field(col, 'foo','bar','foobar')
limit 1
```

The [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function returns the index of a value in the list.

Comment: You should really have some kind of superpower. I'm not speaking of your SQL mastery, but of your ability to *understand* each and every question in a blink of an eye :D

Comment: @juergen-d That seems to work! :) Could you please tell me what 'order by field(column,etc)' actually does?

Comment: @John I took the liberty to edit Juergen's answer to provide a link to the doc of `FIELD()`. As you will see, this is the *exact* function you need!

Comment: @SylvainLeroux If I understand correctly, the order by field compares the first column(?) of the table and compares that with the matched results?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux the function 'field'  is clear to me now. But what does it do in context of the order by? It returns an integer how does the order by clause go by this?

Comment: @John: `field` returns the index first found element in the list. Using this with sort will first return records that are first in the list.